# Collecting multivalued results from replicate in a dataframe

Tags: r, function

Suppose I have some function that produces two columns x and y, which I would like to replicate.

```r
myf <- function(){
  x = rnorm(1)
  y = x + runif(1)
  return(data.frame(x=x, y=y))
}
```

How do I obtain a dataframe of all the results, with two columns x and y?

EDIT: updated function to dependent x & y for clarity

results <- replicate(10, myf())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `simplify = FALSE` flag in `replicate` and `rbind` the results.

```
set.seed(3244)
res <- do.call(rbind, replicate(10, myf(), simplify = FALSE))
res

#             x         y
#1  -0.87455516 0.4195560
#2  -1.45238736 0.5881533
#3   1.19270525 0.3095463
#4   2.07718022 0.8251412
#5   1.60242707 0.6113180
#6   1.06118593 0.3115188
#7   0.38004081 0.4001915
#8  -0.20526611 0.7026361
#9  -0.72092997 0.2526922
#10  0.09140117 0.2004964
```